# How to get response URL in Python requests module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, python-requests, mechanize

I'm tyring to login to a website `login.php` using Python requests module.
If the attempt is successful, the page will be redirected to `index.php`
If not, it remains there in `login.php`.

I was able to do the same with `mechanize` module.

```
import mechanize
b = mechanize.Browser()
url = 'http://localhost/test/login.php'
response = b.open(url)
b.select_form(nr=0)
b.form['username'] = 'admin'
b.form['password'] = 'wrongpwd'
b.method = 'post'
response = b.submit()
print(response.geturl())
if response.geturl() == url:
    print('Failed')
else:
    print('OK')
```

**If login/password is correct**

```
user@linux:~$ python script.py 
http://localhost/test/index.php
OK
user@linux:~$
```

**If login/password is wrong**

```
user@linux:~$ python script.py 
http://localhost/test/login.php
Failed
user@linux:~$
```

My question is how to do the same with `requests` module?

I was trying different approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58248578/python-requests-module-to-verify-if-http-login-is-successful-or-not), but none of them work.

Answer (score 2):

I've took the code from [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58248578/python-requests-module-to-verify-if-http-login-is-successful-or-not) and modified it:

```
import requests
url = 'http://localhost/test/login.php'
values = {'username': 'admin', 'password': 'wrongpwd'}
r = requests.post(url, data=values)
print(r.url)  # prints the final url of the response
```

You can know it's a sure thing because it's [documented in the source code](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L616). All I've done is opened the definition of the `Response` class.

Now, back to your original question.

> Python requests module to verify if HTTP login is successful or not

It depends on whether the website is properly implemented.

When you send a form, any website replies to you with an HTTP response, which contains a status code. A properly implemented website returns different status codes depending on the stuff you've sent. [Here's a list of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). If everything is honky-dory, the status code of the response will be `200`:

```
import requests
url = 'http://localhost/test/login.php'
values = {'username': 'admin', 'password': 'wrongpwd'}
r = requests.post(url, data=values)
print(r.status_code == 200)  # prints True
```

If the user entered the wrong credentials, the status code of the response will be `401` (see the list above). Now, if a website is not implemented properly, it will respond with `200` anyway and you'll have to guess whether the login is successful based on other things, such as `response.content` and `response.url`.

Comment: Thanks @Pavel. Apparently, 200 caused by request to login.php was successful which means this code never submitted the submit button.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58254534/how-to-hit-submit-button-in-web-form-using-python-requests-module